# Count Number of Vowels in Word

Tags: java

I want to write a java code for getting an output like this, but i am not able to do so, instead i get an output something like this "The number of vowels is: 11010" can some one plese tell me what am i doing wrong?

Input :
Montreal

Output :
The number of vowels is: 1 a, 1 e, 1 o

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        
        int cnt[] = new int[5];

    
            
        str = sc.nextLine();
        
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'A') {
                cnt[0]++;
            }
            if (str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'E') {
                cnt[1]++;
            }
            if (str.charAt(i) == 'i' || str.charAt(i) == 'I') {
                cnt[2]++;
            }
            if (str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'O') {
                cnt[3]++;
            }
            if (str.charAt(i) == 'u' || str.charAt(i) == 'U') {
                cnt[4]++;
            }
        }


            System.out.println("The number of vowels is: " + cnt[0] + cnt[1] + cnt[2] + cnt[3] + cnt[4]);
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your print statement to also print the vowel after printing its count:

```java
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("The number of vowels is: "+ cnt[0] + " a, " + cnt[1] + " e, " + cnt[2] + " i, " + cnt[3] + " o, " + cnt[4] + " u";
System.out.println(output);
```

By the way, you could also use a map to store the vowels and counts, instead of an array:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);           
String str = sc.nextLine();
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int i=0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    char letter = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i));
    if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i' ||
        letter == 'o' || letter == 'u') {
        Integer count = map.get(letter);
        map.put(letter, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
    }
}

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (output.length() > 0) output.append(", ");
    output.append(entry.getValue() + " " + entry.getKey());
}
System.out.println("The number of vowels is: " + output.toString());
```

This prints:

```
The number of vowels is: 1 a, 1 e, 1 o
```

Comment: but it still prints the other vowels too   The number of vowels is: 1 a 1 e 0 i 1 o 0 u

Comment: @fayyaz I suggest using my second version, which uses a map to keep track of the counts.  The exact output you want will actually be difficult to obtain if you stick with an array.

Comment: you can do this in a more memory-economic way https://stackoverflow.com/a/67106929/9251397

Comment: it keeps on giving this error        java:10: error: 
cannot find symbol
1

Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
^
  symbol:   class Map
  location: class Problem1
Problem1.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class HashMap
  location: class Problem1
Problem1.java:22: error: package Map does not exist
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        ^

Comment: The code snippet I gave above works, and I have tested it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you forgot the import statements ;-) The kind of question asked implies that the OP is a fresh newcomer to Java and probably hasn't encountered the Collections Library yet, so doesn't know how to import them.

Comment: It's fairly unusual to include import statements for Java answers.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to print the vowel before its count

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        
        int cnt[] = new int[5];

    
            
        str = sc.nextLine();
        char c;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
              c = str.charAt(i);
              if (c == 'a' || c == 'A') {
                cnt[0]++;
              }
              else if (c == 'e' || c == 'E') {
                cnt[1]++;
              }
              else if (c == 'i' || c == 'I') {
                cnt[2]++;
              }
              else if (c == 'o' || c == 'O') {
                cnt[3]++;
              }
              else if (c == 'u' || c == 'U') {
                cnt[4]++;
              }
        }
        boolean b = false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("The number of vowels is:");
        if (cnt[0]!=0){
              sb.append(cnt[0]);
              sb.append(" a");
              b = true;
        }
        if (cnt[1]!=0){
              if (b) {sb.append(",");}
              sb.append(cnt[1]);
              sb.append(" e");
              b = true;
        }
        if (cnt[2]!=0){
              if (b) {sb.append(",");}
              sb.append(cnt[2]);
              sb.append(" i");
              b = true;
        }
        if (cnt[3]!=0){
              if (b) {sb.append(",");}
              sb.append(cnt[3]);
              sb.append(" o");
              b = true;
        }
        if (cnt[4]!=0){
              if (b) {sb.append(",");}
              sb.append(cnt[4]);
              sb.append(" u");
              b = true;
        }


        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        
        
        
    }
}
```